# Alphabetical plist with name and description

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7, plist

How can I make a plist that is alphabetical and has name and description properties? I already have a plist that holds 26 arrays, one for each letter of the alphabet. In each of those arrays, I have some strings that list the name of a cuisine. I want to implement a description for each cuisine. How can I do this and where do I put it to keep the plists' capability of searching, having a index on the side, and being alphabetical?

Thanks

Comment: This kind of thing is what databases are for. Core Data or sqlite3 are good candidates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with the plist (as opposed to using core data), then instead of strings inside your arrays, you should have dictionaries. Each dictionary could have keys like "name" for the name of the cuisine, and "description" for the description. You could have as many other keys as you need if you want to add other attributes for each cuisine.

You could also create custom "cuisine" objects that would have properties like name and description, but then you would have to use an archiver (to convert your custom objects to NSData objects) before you could store the objects in a plist.

Comment: If i decide to have the main dictionary consist of the letters of the alphabet dictionaries consisting of the name and description, how do I access the name and description? a dictionary within a dictionary

Comment: @leeferfeefer, If I understand you correctly, I would use an array of dictionaries as the value for each key (which would be a letter of the alphabet). Each dictionary in the array would be a single cuisine starting with the same letter as its key. Those inner dictionaries would have keys like name and description.

Comment: Can you take a look at this for me please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917274/alphabetical-plist-with-name-and-description-numberofrowsinsection-issues