# Alphabetical plist with name and description numberOfRowsInSection issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7, plist

So, I have a plist that describes multiple cuisines. In my plist, I have 26 arrays, each with a key of a letter of the alphabet. In those arrays, contain multiple cuisines, which are dictionaries. In every dictionary are 2 strings, one for the name of the cuisine and the other for the description of the cuisine. I am very close to implementing this inside a table view controller but I am having a few issues. The main issue is accessing the names and putting it in an array so that it can be used to tell how many rows are in each section, the section being each letter of the alphabet. I keep receiving the error :"-[_NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

This is what I have:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        if (tableView.tag == 1){
            NSString *key = keys[section]; //returns the key(letter) for the section
            NSDictionary *content = cuisines[key]; //returns the dictionary that consists of name and description
            NSString *name = [content valueForKey:@"name"];
            NSMutableArray *keyValues = [@[] mutableCopy];
            [keyValues addObject:name];
            return [keyValues count];
        }else{
            return [filteredcuisines count];
        }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        return [keys count]; //Return the amount of letters for the number of sections
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
```

Also here is a picture of how my dictionary looks:
http://imageshack.com/a/img835/9567/kkv7.png

Here is my search bar code. I need to incorporate the changes I have made to my plist.

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [filteredcuisines removeAllObjects];
    if (searchString.length>0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSArray *matches = [cuisines[key] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            [filteredcuisines addObjectsFromArray:matches];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: filtered cuisines is the filtered cuisine dictionary for the search bar when the user type something to search

Comment: what is there in your keys and cuisines. Are they both arrays?

Comment: oh sorry, cuisines is the dictionary that holds everything. keys is an array that consists of letters A-Z. Each letter is an array that can hold multiple dictionaries that can each represent a cuisine. Each dictionary cuisine has a name and description.

Comment: Can you post the numberOfSections method?

Comment: Also, you seem to always return 1 if the tableView.tag==1. Always keyValues will have one object. If so why you need all those manipulations?

Comment: well how do i count all of the cuisine names properly?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of your cuisines dictionary so we can see its structure. Somewhere, you're accessing a string that you think is an array, that's why you get that error.

Comment: Ok i added it at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "content" which you get from cuisines[key] should be an array, not a dictionary. It's also not clear what you're trying to do with the keyValues array. I think your method can be simplified to just this,

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        if (tableView.tag == 1){
            NSString *key = keys[section]; 
            NSArray *content = cuisines[key];  
            return content.count;
        }else{
            return [filteredcuisines count];
        }
}
```

I'm assuming that you get keys from using calling allKeys on your dictionary, and then sorting that alphabetically. If that's so, then you can get the name for your table view in cellForRowAtIndexPath with this,

```
    NSArray *arrayForSingleLetter = self.cuisines[keys[indexPath.section]];
    cell.textLabel.text = arrayForSingleLetter[indexPath.row][@"name"];
```

Filtering your array will have to be modified to something like this,

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [filteredcuisines removeAllObjects];
    if (searchString.length>0) {

        NSArray *arrayForSingleLetter = self.cuisines[[searchString substringToIndex:1]];
        NSIndexSet *indxs = [arrayForSingleLetter indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [dict[@"name"] rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound;
        }];

        [indxs enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [filteredcuisines addObject:arrayForSingleLetter[idx][@"name"]];
        }];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Well this does work, it does not allow me to access the name and put them in a table view. How do I set the text like: cell.textLabel.text = content[indexPath.row]; does not work. This is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @leeferfeefer, of course that won't work, you have to use indexPath.section to get the individual sections, then indexPath.row to get the individual dictionaries in your array, then finally, objectForKey:@"name" to get the name. I've updated my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: Great thanks. This makes sense. I was not approaching this correctly

Comment: How can I implement the correct use of a search bar. I have edited my above question. This is what I had before I updated my plist to have a description.

Comment: @leeferfeefer, it depends on what kind of searches you're trying to do. Do you want to search just on the names of the cuisines?

Comment: @leeferfeefer, I've updated my answer with more code.

Comment: @leeferfeefer, it worked fine for me. What does it do? Do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors. Just noticed that it has to be exact. Like starting with a Capital letter. how can i change it so that the text field does not have to be case-sensitive?

Comment: @leeferfeefer, yeah, well the way the code is written currently, it does have to have the correct capitalization. That's not hard to fix, you should try to figure that out yourself. I'm not going to write your whole app for you.

Comment: One more question, for each dictionary in each letter array in my cuisines plist, I have added another array that includes ingredients. How can I search by 1 or more ingredients and have the results show up as the cuisines that have those ingredients?